# Get Unique or Distinct values of more than one column

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume i have Table with more than 2 or 3 three fields. In that field i want to get Unique values from that table.

**Input:**

Table Name:  **Test**

```
column1   column2  column3
  A         P        Y
  B         P        X
  A         Q        Z
  C         R        Y
  B         R        Y
```

**Output:**

```
column1    column2   column3
  A          P         Y
  B          Q         X
  C          R         Z
```

Here order is not import but i want to get unique values from different columns.

Comment: Is it MySQL or MS Sql or Oracle?

Comment: Kindly refer this link for oracle https://community.oracle.com/thread/622240

Comment: `B    Q    X` do you get valid data by such a query!?

Comment: In MySQL i want get the values

Comment: Every column need not have the same count of unique values, which means, this is not possible,unless you do a union for individual column.

Comment: I did by using Union but column names is not coming( only one column name is showing). But actually i want different columns. It is possible. If possible provide the query.

Comment: This is a very, very special request, because in SQL the columns shown in a (result) row are supposed to be related. In your query this isn't the case (A has nothing more to do with P than with Q for example). So rather than writing such query, one would write one to get one value per row such as Maheswaran shows in his answer. Maybe the need for such strange query even indicates a bad database design and you might want to change it.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I have the same question- it's not necessarily a super special request. A view with this information (even though the data is not related) can help reporting engines to dynamically know what all of the possible search values are being used. +1 for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest approach could be UNION of all the unique values across every column like below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_value FROM
(
    SELECT 'column1' as column_name,
           Column1 as column_value
    FROM test
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'column2' as column_name,
           Column2
    FROM test
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'colum3' as column_name,
           Column3
    FROM test
)
```

Answer (score 2):

In oracle you can use this query:

```
select column1, column2, column3 
from (select rownum rw, column1 from (select distinct column1 from test)) t1 
     full outer join
     (select rownum rw, column2 from (select distinct column2 from test)) t2 on (t2.rw = t1.rw)
     full outer join
     (select rownum rw, column3 from (select distinct column3 from test)) t3 on (t3.rw = t2.rw or t3.rw = t1.rw);
```

`ROWNUM` is a pseudocolumn which gives a row number to each row.

Note that if the columns have unequal number of unique values there can be NULL values in some rows/columns.

The idea is to find all unique values in each column (3 subqueries), assign row number to each row in each subquery and full join all the results by row number.